# Can someone explain this example of deleting elements from a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

The following example appears in the MATLAB tutorial:

```
X = [16  2 13;
     5  11  8;
     9   7 12;
     4  14  1]
```

Using a single subscript deletes a single element, or sequence of elements, and reshapes the remaining elements into a row vector. So:

```
X(2:2:10) = []
```

results in:

```
X = [16 9 2 7 13 12 1]
```

Mysteriously, the entire 2nd row and the first two elements in the 4th row have been deleted, but I can't see the correspondence between the position of the deleted elements and the index vector `2:2:10`. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Oops! I probably gave you more info than you needed, since I thought you were asking about the linear-indexing part, not the vector-creation part. Either way, happy to help! =)... and sorry about that jackass 2pac littering your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example you gave shows [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). When you have a multidimensional array and you give it a single scalar or vector, it indexes along each column from top to bottom and left to right. Here's an example of indexing into each dimension:

```
mat = [1 4 7; ...
       2 5 8; ...
       3 6 9];
submat = mat(1:2, 1:2);
```

`submat` will contain the top left corner of the matrix: `[1 4; 2 5]`. This is because the first `1:2` in the subindex accesses the first dimension (rows) and the second `1:2` accesses the second dimension (columns), extracting a 2-by-2 square. If you don't supply an index for each dimension, separated by commas, but instead just one index, MATLAB will index into the matrix as though it were one big column vector:

```
submat = mat(3, 3);     % "Normal" indexing: extracts element "9"
submat = mat(9);        % Linear indexing: also extracts element "9"
submat = mat([1 5 6]);  % Extracts elements "1", "5", and "6"
```

See the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) for more detail.

Comment: In that case, surely only the elements at positions 2 and 10 should have been deleted, but it appears 5 elements have been deleted

Comment: 2:2:10 create a vector, starting at the number 2 and moving in steps of 2 until the number 10.

Comment: great, the vector creation part is what I wasn't "getting"

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

It basically starts from the second element in this example and goes upto tenth element (column wise) in steps of 2 and deletes corresponding elements. The remaining elements result in a row vector.