# How do I remove elements at a set of indices in a vector in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a vector with 100 elements. I have another vector with index positions of elements I want to remove from this vector.

How do I do this?

Comment: Here are a couple questions that are very nearly duplicates, since removing array elements is a component of the answers (although other issues are also covered): [MATLAB: what's the most elegant (efficient) way to delete known elements in a matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683488/matlab-whats-the-most-elegant-efficient-way-to-delete-known-elements-in-a-mat), [matlab: delete elements from matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572021/matlab-delete-elements-from-matrix). I think I'll try to edit some titles and tags so these are easier to find in the future. ;)

Answer (score 43):

```
vector(indecies) = []
```

example:

```
>> a = 1:10;
>> a([3,4,7]) = []

a =

     1     2     5     6     8     9    10
```